# PHP get name and value while using for

Tags: php

I have this problem that when I use array as such

```
Array
(
    [11] => /2
    [10] => /2
)
```

I'm unable to get the array name or the value when I use

```
for($i=0; $i < count($_SESSION['CHECKBOX']);$i++){
```

how can I get the name? and value? separate?

Comment: Don't use an incremental for loop (there's not too often a need for them in PHP, since `foreach` is usually more appropriate). Instead use `foreach ($_SESSION['CHECKBOX'] as $key => $value)`

Comment: Any specific reason to use for loop only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an array `$_SESSION['CHECKBOX']`, you can use:

```
foreach($_SESSION['CHECKBOX'] as $key=>$value) {
    echo $key . '->' . $value . '<br />';
}
```

to get the key and values.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize the [`foreach`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) construct:

> The foreach construct provides an easy way to iterate over arrays.
> foreach works only on arrays and objects, and will issue an error when
> you try to use it on a variable with a different data type or an
> uninitialized variable. There are two syntaxes:

It will iterate your array and assign the key to the `$key` variable and the value to the `$value` array:

```
foreach($_SESSION['CHECKBOX'] as $key => $value){
    echo "$key = $value";
}
```

Or concatenate the strings:

```
echo $key . '=' . $value;
```